# How can I develop a message wall in Python + Django?

Tags: jquery, python, ajax, django, python-2.7

So i need to develop a messaging wall.

What this means is i have a page where users can post data too, so for example they can post "Hello, how are you?". This then would get submitted to all relevant users...

The way i have this currently setup is as follows:

User visit page, a function is run to pull all the current wall messages from the database and display it on the screen using an AJAX call... Through jQuery, I then use the set_interval function to run the same function above every 1 second. This is so that the information on the message window is current. As well, if a user posts something to wall, this very same update function is called.

This way everything is always up to date, or about to be up to date in at most 1 seconds time.

So I'm sure most of you are thinking, well what's the problem... The problem is that the server will receive a request every 1 second for every user that is on the message page for as long as they are on the message page. So it adds some unwanted stress to the server.

Is there any way for me to have the server notify the user when there is any changes to the message wall, as opposed having the current system?

Comment: You can look into [node.js](http://nodejs.org/) and [socket.io](http://socket.io/get-started/chat/), however this is javascript and not Python+Django.

Comment: You could probably try and use websockets to do that.

Answer (score 0):

When you need to keep long user connection for informing him about events immediately, then you probably need some async approaches. And they will use websockets.

In python you can choose [Tornado](http://tornadoweb.org/).

And at client size one of the best choice is [SockJS](https://github.com/sockjs/sockjs-client).

Also, there is possibility to process async task by Tornado, and other web site will work with django. In that case you'll need to implement communication between tornado and django. It could be done using queues.

Take a look at [centrifuge](https://github.com/FZambia/centrifuge) project. This project use Tornado, SockJS.